# Webview inflate error in android marshmallow

Tags: android, webview, webkit, android-6.0-marshmallow

I had developed an android app which contains webview in its main activity
webview will be loaded on Oncreate method on mainactivity
Application works fine on Kitkat, lollipop,but when deployed on marshmallow it is giving the below error
at

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

### Stack trace

```
01-19 14:14:47.250    9049-9049/com.mobility.hsm.reboottest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mobility.hsm.reboottest, PID: 9049
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mobility.hsm.reboottest/com.mobility.hsm.reboottest.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2171)
            at com.mobility.hsm.reboottest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:54)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6271)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2171)
            at com.mobility.hsm.reboottest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:54)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6271)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2171)
            at com.mobility.hsm.reboottest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:54)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6271)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: For security reasons, WebView is not allowed in privileged processes
            at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:152)
            at android.webkit.WebView.getFactory(WebView.java:2277)
            at android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated(WebView.java:2272)
            at android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.java:2331)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3789)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3892)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:573)
            at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:55)
            at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:597)
            at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:542)
            at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:525)
            at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:512)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
            at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2171)
```

### Layout.xml

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Weview Test"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Result"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:src="@drawable/stoptest"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/webView" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Comment: what is `Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView `

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace. Please also post the layout file that is causing the problem.

Comment: pasted full stack trace and layout .xml